# How can I convert South and West coordinates to align to X/East and Y/North in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, georeferencing

So I have an image I am trying to georeference using QGIS. The coordinates I want the image to be placed at are:

```
top left = 50N, 140E
top right = 50N, 160W
bottom left = 15N, 140E
bottom right = 15N, 160W
```

But when I attempt to load those into QGIS - Georeference tool, it only appears to want:

```
X / East
Y / North
```

How would I convert my coordinates from W to E as the tool appears to want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my issue was in the Coordinate Reference System I was using. Since it crossed the anti-meridian line, I needed to change the CRS to "move" the CRS so my image can lay between those points.

This then allowed me to simply use the georeference tool as I wanted and automatically get the data/points for the image.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without using the georeference tool as you have the information to write your own world file.
From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) the world file structure is as follows

```
Line 1: A: pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel
Line 2: D: rotation about y-axis
Line 3: B: rotation about x-axis
Line 4: E: pixel size in the y-direction in map units, almost always negative[3]
Line 5: C: x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
Line 6: F: y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
```

You should be able to find the the size in pixels and therefore calculate how big each pixel is.
From your coordinates it looks like there is no rotation so 0.
The last two lines require a bit more maths as you have to calculate the centre  of a pixel.

World files should be saved  with the same name as the image but a different extension such as .wld.

Here is an example

```
0.50000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
-0.50000000
438007.16150000
193255.10440000
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a misunderstanding. I believe the labels on the entry fields are just saying that first axis is positive in the East direction and labeled X while the 2nd axis is positive in the North direction and labeled Y. Try using negative values for the west longitude values.

Also for latitude-longitude values, enter longitude values in the X / East field and the latitude values in the Y / North field.